# How do I make the backend of a statistics app?

Tags: php, node.js, heroku

I'm not asking for a step by step guide or anything but rather a few guidelines from someone who has done anything similar before.

I want to try and make an application which backend will basically receive hundreds/thousands of samples every minute (with data in json format) from a third party API and calculate and store statistics, to then serve them to a client app/website through my API. I dont think I can store the samples, specially since I will try to make this with free hosting like Heroku's free tier for the API, and for the db I will see.

It will be the first time I do anything like this so I'd like some guidelines, like, what do you think is the best technology for anything like this? NodeJS, php? I would learn either from scratch. What about the database?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give us an idication about which type of statistics you are thinking? Count, mean, average, std. dev., variance, column frequencies, anova, etc. See: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/whatstat

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The statistics will be pretty simple I think, Im thinking just averages, percentages (as in % of times the samples or a subgroup have a certain feature), and the like, and how those evolve over time